# Help with BJT design

Tags: bjt

I am going into my senior year as an electrical engineering student and I am having some trouble turning what I have learned in my classes into designing transistor circuits. I have taken a few transistor analysis classes and I am very comfortable with basic circuit laws, but on homework and tests, we are almost always given a problem which gives component values and expects us to find the operating point, and then do small signal analysis. I am getting stuck because I am not really sure where to start when designing a BJT circuit instead of just solving a homework problem.

For example, I want to build a circuit which will take a 0 to 3v3 signal from a microcontroller and turn it into a 0-10v signal.

This is what I was attempting to try:

A common emitter amplifier in series with a common collector amp (although idk if I need the CC since I want to drive a 200kohm load which I may be able to drive from the CE?).

I also know that instead of capacitively coupling the input, I could use that 1.5v (0-3.3v input signal) to help bias the BJT, but in classes we always have coupling capacitor on the input, and so during DC analysis, the input signal bias is not relevant. I can just use superposition to find a thevenin equivalent, right?

I am also unsure about how to relate parameters used in classes (like beta, transconductance) to how a datasheet for a particular transistor presents information. For example, the 2n2222 datasheet (and as far as I know any BJT datasheet) doesn't include the traditional IV biasing curves I am used to seeing.

I feel a bit slow at the moment since I can usually get some sort of sense of where to start, but I am having trouble doing that.

I would appreciate it if someone would kind of outline how they would approach designing a circuit like this which may give me a platform to build off of.

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds to me like you want a logic level converter rather than an analogue solution.

Comment: Yeah please clarify if this is a digital (on/off) signal or an analog one. Those would require very different solutions.

Comment: As already pointed out, it is very difficult to ***design*** a circuit if you haven't specified the input source and its details, the output load and its details, and various goals of the circuit (digital vs analog and things such as frequency and linearity and much more.) We can't write a book that covers all possibilities. That's crazy to ask for. So provide a very specific example case, please.

Comment: Chmod, are you still around and interested? Or not?

Comment: omg I forgot I asked this question! @periblepsis , the signal is analog, and on top of that, the amplifier must have a 1kHz to 200kHz passband... Just thinking now though, I guess I could do PWM, amplify the logic signal and filter the carrier much like a class D amplifier... thoughts?

Comment: @chmod777 1 kHz to 200 kHz is not a struggle. So put that aside. But the analog signal source needs to be specified (dynamic range of RMS input and source impedance at a minimum.) I gather it will have a DC bias. I also now gather you might also consider PWM -- though you'd need a very high frequency for that to result in 1 kHz to 200 kHz on the down-end of things. But assuming a DAC for now, it's not likely to have low output impedance. So that number is needed. Driving 200 kOhm is easy. But less if its a piezo. So details there also matter.

Comment: @periblepsis here is the load: https://www.piezodrive.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/PDm200-V9-Datasheet-R5.pdf . It drives two transducers in the “three wire bender” configuration. The MCU is https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU32/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/SAM-D5x-E5x-Family-Data-Sheet-DS60001507.pdf . DAC has 5kohm output impedance (pg 1856). Transducers: https://senscomp.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Series-600-Open-Face-Ultrasonic-Sensor-with-Parylene-Spec-01Oct22.pdf .

Comment: @periblepsis my current implementation is just an opamp to step 0-3v3 to 0-10 as per the power amplifier configuration I am using. However, I think I should be able to get a stronger signal out from the transducers than I currently am. I am not in the lab until tomorrow, but I can see how much power the main amp actually outputs with the current system.

Comment: @chmod777 Thanks. So need to drive that module. I see a fixed gain of 20. I have no idea whata three wire bender requires from that unit. The piezo driver has some specs. But if you want to get the best from it, then someone needs to figure out what that wire bender needs to get its best, translate that information in context of the piezo driver you have, and work out then what the maximum input to it can be based up that 20-gain it has. I could assume stuff. But I'd rather not. But if assuming, I'd assume +/-100 V max or 70 V RMS. Or < 600 Ohm piezo load. But *verify*!